# How to invoke one declared variable inside file into another file?

Tags: java

Suppose, I've one file `MainProgram.java`

inside this file i've declared JTextField as `JTextField locationInfo;`

Now i've different file `GoListener.java`

and i would like to invoke that declared variable `JTextField locationInfo;` into `GoListener.java` file, but how to do that? please help

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: `MainProgram.java` is not a class, it's a file. I think you should go through a [basic tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) to understand basic concepts of programming.

Comment: That's called a getter, and that's the very basis of OOP... You will find it at the beginning of every Java tutorial.

Comment: I edited my question please see this again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want is called getter.
example :
in `GoListener.java`

```
MainProgram main=new MainProgram();
JTextField myLocation=main.getMyLocationInfo(); //this will return the jTextField
```

now : `MainProgram.java`

```
public JTextField getMyLocationInfo()
{ 
    return locationInfo;
}
```

Comment: Okay, I did impplemented as you said it was getter.. at the moment it's not giving me any knd of errors, but are you sure this will return the same method of one files information to another file(where i'm working)??

Comment: the getter return a variable from another class. Ex : you have in textfiled : "Hi TEST" , in GoListner.java you'll find in MyLocation.getText(); "Hi TEST"

Comment: if this answer is enough don't forget to upvote/accept the answer :)

Comment: Okay, i'll accept but it's showing After 2 minuter.. and can't vote up sorry don't have enough reputations sorry :p